# razor engine syntax inside javascript tag for non string variables

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razorengine

It seems odd but i can't pass a non string variable (e.g. boolean variable) to a javascript code. I get an error says:`syntax error` in view engine.
razor engine:

```
@{bool serverVariable=true;}

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var clientVariable = @serverVariable;
});
```

of course it runs perfectly even though view engine has an error, but i cannot understand what cause this? and how can i omit this syntax error in razor view engine.
As an alternative i can also put it in quotes, like:`var clientVariable = "@serverVariable";` but it will render as `var clientVariable = "true";` meanwhile i expect `var clientVariable = true;`

Comment: @Andreas I already mentioned that "it would work even though view engine has an error". so the answer is: It's a known bug and It's based on `VS` version and/or `Razor` version. right?

Comment: _It's a known bug_: Yes -> https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/760339/valid-javascript-razor-syntax-marked-as-syntax-error